# Finding the cauchy integral for $I(n)=\int_\gamma \frac{\cos{z}}{(z-z_0)^3}{dz}$ when $\gamma: |z|=3.$

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

$$\int_\gamma \frac{\cos z}{(z-z_0)^3}dz,\quad  \gamma \colon |z|=3$$

I was able to find the solution for this problem which included 
$z=2 \in \gamma, -3<z<3$, therefore $-3<2<3$. And when comparing to Cauchy formula we find that $n+1=3 \Rightarrow n=2$.

Now the rest of the solution is obvious. What I wasn't able to understand was how did we determine that $<=2 \in \gamma$  and that it is the point that we are looking for.

Please note that English isn't my first language so I'm having problems translating the exact mathematical words to English so pardon the quality of this post. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You haven’t define $n$.

Comment: If $z_0$ is a point in the interior of $\gamma$ then the answer is $-\pi i \cos z_0$.

Comment: What is $z_0$? What is the advantage of getting $2 \in \mathrm {int} \gamma$?

Comment: So what? We can simply use Cauchy's integral formula for derivative. Here $\cos z$ is entire and hence analytic on and inside of $\gamma$.

Comment: I'm well aware of the answer which is $\frac{2 \pi i}{2i} (-\cos(2))$

Comment: But why is Z = 2 the point we chose ?

Comment: Then Cauchy's integral formula for derivative asserts that the integral value will be equal to $\frac {2 \pi i} {2} f''(z_0)$ where $z_0 \in \mathrm {int} (\gamma)$ and $f(z)=\cos z$.

Comment: Why are you using $2$ here? Is $z_0=2$ in your question?

Comment: D_C no it is not in my question, it is part of the solution, it just says that because |z|=3 therefore -3<z<3 and therefore z=2 is the solution for the aforementioned equation so -3<2<3

Comment: $|z|=3$ doesn't imply $-3<z<3$. Rather it is more than you have stated. It is a circle centered at the origin and radius $3$ or in other words $|z|=3 \implies z=3e^{it}$ where $0 \le t \le 2 \pi$.

Comment: Are complex numbers well ordered?

Comment: This needs editing. Where is $z_0?$ What is $n?$ Include all hypotheses, clearly and precisely. We don't know how to read your mind. Your language problem is no excuse for having variables floating around unexplained.

Comment: zhw ofcourse it isn't .. n is the n from the Cauchy integral formula.. the example does not in any way explain where z0 is unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $z_0 \notin \overline{D(0,3)}$ thus exists $s>0$ such that $|z_0| \geq 3+s$

Then $f(z)=\frac{\cos{z}}{(z-z_0)^3}$ is holomorphic on the disc $D(0,3+\frac{s}{2}) \supset \gamma$ thus from the theorem of Cachy in convex regions we have that $\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz=0$

Now if $|z_0|<3$ we have from Cauchy's the integral formula for derivatives for $g(z)=\cos{z}$ we have that $$2 \pi i g''(z_0)=\int_{\gamma}\frac{\cos{z_0}}{(z-z_0)^3}dz$$